# don't understand python's behaviour of three dimensional lists (references to sublists are the same)

Tags: python

I don't understand why the following code behaves the way it does.

```
import numpy as np


nbr_arrays = 4
nbr_fields_per_array = 3
nbr_subfields_per_field = 2

# pre-allocate zeros list
zeros = np.zeros(nbr_subfields_per_field)

data = []
for array in range(nbr_arrays):

    # pre-allocate the subarray 
    empty_array = []
    for empty_array_index in range(nbr_fields_per_array):
        empty_array.append(zeros)

    # append pre subarray to data
    data.append(empty_array)

    # fill up data
    for j in range(nbr_fields_per_array):
        for k in range(nbr_subfields_per_field):
            data[array][j][k] = j*k*array
```

The generated output `data` reads now:

```
[[array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.])],
 [array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.])],
 [array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.])],
 [array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.]), array([ 0.,  6.])]]
```

Even `zeros` reads completely differently:

```
array([ 0.,  6.])
```

If I look at the identify of the different lists, this is what I get:

```
id(data[0][0])
Out[72]: 45790208

id(data[1][0])
Out[66]: 45790208

id(data[2][0])
Out[67]: 45790208

id(data[3][0])
Out[68]: 45790208

id(zeros)
Out[69]: 45790208
```

why are all the references the same? and why does `zero` suddenly contain non-zero values?

I'd really appreciate it if somebody **could explain me what exactly is happening here**, and **how I have to modify my code to see the expected behaviour** (output).

**EDIT:**

not using `zeros` but using `[[0]*nbr_subfields_per_field for x in range(nbr_fields_per_array)]` instead gives me the expected result. but why? why doesn't the original code work?
Modified code that works:

```
data = []
for array in range(nbr_arrays):
    empty_array = [[0]*nbr_subfields_per_field for x in range(nbr_fields_per_array)]

    ''' this is causing the weird behaviour 
    empty_array = []
    for empty_array_index in range(nbr_fields_per_array):
        empty_array.append(zeros)
    '''

    data.append(empty_array)

    for j in range(nbr_fields_per_array):
        for k in range(nbr_subfields_per_field):
            data[array][j][k] = j*k*array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # pre-allocate zeros list
> zeros = np.zeros(nbr_subfields_per_field)
> ```

This creates a single object.

> ```
> for empty_array_index in range(nbr_fields_per_array):
>     empty_array.append(zeros)
> ```

This keeps appending the same object.

Stop pre-allocating.

Comment: does this mean that `a = zeros` creates a reference to the object? in this case I would have to make a deep copy of zeros to achieve what I want to do, right?

Comment: Yes, Python assignments are always references, rather copies. To copy an object, either use a function (often its class's constructor will work) or try the `copy` module.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can set up multidimensional arrays for you, if you want. Since you're going to initialize the whole array immediately after creating it, the `empty` method seems like the most appropriate:

```
data = np.empty((nbr_arrays, nbr_fields_per_array, nbr_subfields_per_field))
```